Central a/c unit leaking water through ceiling
The central a/c unit in the condo I rent is leaking water through the ceiling. The thermostat works fine, the air filter is new, and the a/c successfully cools the unit when it runs. Technician came out this morning to unclog the drain line. He assured the problem had been fixed, however, after running the a/c for some hours, on and off, the leak reappeared just now. If the a/c drain was indeed unclogged yet the a/c continues to leak, what else could be the cause of the problem given that the a/c operates fine outside of it leaking?
Attached are images of areas around the a/c where I've spotted water.




You're in a condo and you rent.  Call the the owner or owner's property management company. Tell them the problem is not rectified.

If the humidity is very high, and air can infiltrate, e.g., through open windows, doors or through the walls themselves, if they lack a vapor barrier, water can condense and accumulate on any cold part of the AC, such as the line near the evaporator, before it enters the area where a pan underneath catches drips.
It is also possible there are leaks from the roof around the AC. If it only leaks after heavy rain, and for a day or so afterward, have the AC and roof checked from outside.
In the meantime, what can you do?

Close all doors and windows while the AC runs.
Set the AC temperature a bit higher.
Run a cotton string from where the leak in the ceiling starts down to a bucket. The water, hopefully, will drip along the string. Yep, that's not the greatest, but keeps the carpet dry. sigh

